# Bypass Security alert on safari browser for seamless automation

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, safari, glasspane

How to Bypass the  "the safari window is remotely controlled by an automated test".

Is there any way to disable the safari glass pane.

Comment: Probably not and I don't see a reason why someone would need this.

Comment: Are you running safari headless?? You could try using a user path. Why Safari? Why not Chrome or Firefox?